# Inf and NaN cannot be JSON encoded

Tags: php, json

If we json_encode an array which has Inf or NaN then we get : Inf and NaN cannot be JSON encoded

The workaround as mentioned here - https://levels.io/inf-nan-json_encode/ is :

```
json_encode(unserialize(str_replace(array('NAN;','INF;'),'0;',serialize($reply))));
```

Is there any update on getting this resolved better using the latest PHP versions, say 8.0 or 8.1 ?

Comment: If a value of `0` is fine, you can use `JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR`.

Comment: What would "resolved better" mean exactly? The limitation is not with PHP, it's with JSON. [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-6) puts it this way "Numeric values that cannot be represented in the grammar below (such as Infinity and NaN) are not permitted."